# python matplotlib doesn't keep scale

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to read from one csv file values for memory in one server and try to make a graph with them, but the axis doesn' keep the proportional to the values, here and example, in the x axis a, 1,2,3,4,5,11 all of them keep the same space I want 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 although the graphs is not consisten in this way it is linear in but it it not true.

is there any other way to make this graphs?

I am expecting linear with all values in the x-axis and y-axis, not logaritmi.

Comment: Show us the code you wrote, even if it is not yet working correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing in actual numbers and not text strings of numbers?